# Catching signals sent by runit (sv stop <id>)

Tags: python, runit

I have a python program that is running a number of worker processes. Because this has to be handled properly to avoid orphaned processes, I have implemented a signal handler to shutdown all worker processes.

The program starts more or less like this:

1. Start process pool (starts X number of workers)
2. Register signal handlers (`signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, my_signal_handler)`). I also add another signal handler for `SIGINT` with the same handler.
3. Start seperate thread polling backend (database) and add the tasks to process pool.
4. On main thread, poll process pool for results (there is a result `multiprocessing.Queue` that the individual workers add the results to).

The idea is that the two seperate threads started in 3 and 4 keep the tasks running through the machinery.

If I start this manually and call `kill -15 <pid>` or `kill -2 <pid>` it correctly shuts everything down, waits for processes to `join()`. Reading from the documentation, runit sends a `TERM` to the process, followed by `CONT`. However, running this under runit, it simply shows the standard `ok: down: <my_program>: 1s, normally up`, but the process is still running in the background (even the main process, it is UNTOUCHED).

If I then afterwards go out and manually kill the process, I can see in the log file that it shuts down correctly. What am I doing wrong? It seems that runit ONLY kills the 3-line shell script I created to activate the virtualenv, but leaves the actual python process behind.

Even if I run the "run" script directly, I can either run `kill` or Ctrl+C (same as `SIGINT`) and it shuts down correctly.

Comment: Have you considered using a different mechanism to run, control and monitor the workers?  Supervisord, for example.  It might not have the same behavior problems...

Comment: I have, but as it is we have a lot of other services under runit, so it would be annoying to have two "competing" tools.

Comment: @Charles, `runit` can have custom hooks written to replace its default signaling behavior, so it can do literally anything supervisord or kin can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so after some extensive testing I figured it out.

Runit will send the kill signal to the `run` script, which does not propogate it by default. What you need to make sure is that you call `exec python yourscript.py` in the end. Similarly, if your `run` script calls another shell script (ie. one that activates your virtualenv or similar), it must do so with `exec` as well.

Samples:

`run`:

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 002
2>&1
exec chpst -uanalytics cliscript router
```

`cliscript`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Resolve script path, assuming that the script resides in $(ABSPATH)/bin
SCRIPTPATH="$0"
if [ -h "$SCRIPTPATH" ]; then
    SCRIPTPATH=$(readlink -e "$0")
fi
ABSPATH=$(dirname "$(cd "$(dirname "$SCRIPTPATH")"; pwd -L)")

# Load the virtual environment
source "$ABSPATH/venv/bin/activate"

# Set up environment
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

exec python "$ABSPATH/bin/processing-cli.py" $@
```

Take note of the `exec` being called when we "pass" control to the next script or python itself.

Comment: Your question didn't contain enough information to make this diagnosis, by the way -- one could reasonably assume that you'd read the sample run scripts, all of which correctly use `exec`, before writing your own, and the question didn't an actual sample of the failing runscript by which to disabuse someone of this notion.

Comment: ...also, `$@` needs to be `"$@"` if you don't want your arguments to be string-split. (Effectively, unquoted `$@` is exactly the same as `$*`).

Comment: I know, which is also why I put the answer here. I did not think it would be relevant to include the scripts - it's only after I found out that exec was important that it would've made sense to include them, and by then I knew what was wrong :)